# How do I punctuate a series of quotes from TV shows?

Tags: punctuation

I want to write this:

> “Dy- No-Mite!” “Stifle it Edith.” “Good Night John Boy.” “Nanu Nanu.” “God will get you for that.” “Book em Danno.” “Da plane, da plane.” “Eizabeth, I’m coming.” “Kiss my grits!” “Marcia, Marcia, Marcia.”  “Who loves you, baby?” “Just one more thing.”

Do commas go between quotations or as part of the quotation? What if there is a question mark or exclamation mark as part of the quote?